# RegisterHotKey API issue - not releasing when application is closed

Tags: winapi

I am having the same as this.

http://win32apiforum.com/topic.php?f=15&t=17

I used RegisterHotKey API to provide hot keys for certain events. Key combination Ctrl+C is registered successfully and my application works fine. If I don’t close my application and run another application (such as Notepad or Microsoft Word) where Ctrl+C key combination is use to copy selected text then this call is trapped by my application as it is registered hotkey and windows did not get to see it at all. That’s why copy selected text functionality is not working in other applications which is major flaw.

I looked into many forums and MSDN and tried to find work around however did not get anything. Could anyone of you please suggest anyway out for the issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use another key combination. Or catch Ctrl+C using SetWindowsHookEx with WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook. Hook function allows to continue keyboard event handling and doesn't prevent another programs to handle it.

Comment: I totally for got this option. hhmmm... nice.